# How do I sign a message using web3py?

Tags: web3.py, python

How can I sign this message using web3py?

Based on the documentation, I realized that I need to use [eth_signTypedData](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/v5/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.sign_typed_data). But it is not clear to me how to send data (space, proposal, choice, etc.).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to sign a transaction and interact with a smart contract. You can have a try with the code below

```
tokenInstance = w3.eth.contract(address="Target Contract Address", abi= "Target Contract Abi")
callInstance = tokenInstance.functions.FunctionName(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3)

tx = callInstance.build_transaction({
    'from': sender.address,
    'value': 0,
    'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(address),
})

signed_tx = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx,privateKey)
emitted = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
```

replace FunctionName, parameter1, parameter2 and parameter3 with the input parameters you would like to use.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, because signing transaction is not the same as signing messages.

Answer (score 0):

For signing typed type e.g. for EIP-712 [you can find an example here the source code](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/_modules/eth_defi/usdc/eip_3009.html#make_eip_3009_transfer).

You can use `LocalAccount._sign()` to sign a hash that is generated with `eip712_encode_hash()`. This does not does any RPC call, but uses a locally imported private key.